# write a query without CTE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

How can write this query widout CTE?

```
with cte as(
select FK#GharardadeAsli,MAX(PK#Shenase) as PK#Shenase,Max(TarikheSabt) as TarikheSabt from TBL#Gharardad where FK#GharardadeAsli is not null group by FK#GharardadeAsli
)
select * from v#gharardad inner join cte on cte.PK#Shenase = v#gharardad.[Shenase]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write it as a sub-query.

```
select * 
  from v#gharardad 
  inner join (select FK#GharardadeAsli,
                     MAX(PK#Shenase) as PK#Shenase,
                     Max(TarikheSabt) as TarikheSabt 
                from TBL#Gharardad 
               where FK#GharardadeAsli is not null 
               group by FK#GharardadeAsli
             ) sub on sub.PK#Shenase = v#gharardad.[Shenase]
```

Comment: Can u tell me its linq equal?

Comment: I am trying by myself but i have so problem with group in linq.It seems harder than sql

Comment: You are right - not so easy.  I have something, but the grouping is off.  You might consider throwing out a new question on how to convert the sql statement into Linq.  It will be more visible with more answers

Comment: In proper lingo, this answer uses a **derived table**, not a subquery.

Answer (score 2):

What about

```
SELECT  *
FROM    (
          select  FK#GharardadeAsli
                  , MAX(PK#Shenase) as PK#Shenase
                  , Max(TarikheSabt) as TarikheSabt 
          from    TBL#Gharardad 
          where   FK#GharardadeAsli is not null 
          group by FK#GharardadeAsli
        ) v
        INNER JOIN (
          select  FK#GharardadeAsli
                  , MAX(PK#Shenase) as PK#Shenase
                  , Max(TarikheSabt) as TarikheSabt 
          from    TBL#Gharardad 
          where   FK#GharardadeAsli is not null 
          group by FK#GharardadeAsli
        ) cte ON cte.Shenase = v.Shenase
```

Comment: Can u tell me its linq equal?

Comment: @LightWing - sorry, I have no idea.

Answer (score -1):

Declare Table Variable And Do The Same Thing

Comment: I have an offer for u accept the correct answer by click on it tick symbol